# how Filters handle Session

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

some of you advise me to **handle sessions** using **filters**. I studied a little about the filter following some guides found on the internet,  and  wrote a filter referring this  [guide](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/http-session-handling-tutorial-using-servlet-filters-session-error-filter-servlet-filter/).

I saw that the filter is called for every component of my page (css, images etc); is there a way to call it just when a jsp or a servlet is load? I need a method that can understand if jsp or a servlet is load, in order to make some stuff inside my filter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Just change the `url-pattern` for your session filter.

If you are using some web framework (spring mvc,...) with one dispatching servlet, you can map your filter only to this servlet using `servlet-name` and requests to other resources (js, css) will not be intercepted by this filter.

Comment: This means that if i have one millions servlet i should have one millions servlet-name tag right?

Comment: Not necessary. You have two options when mapping filters to servlets: you can specify the url-pattern or servlet-name. But you want to map your filter to all but static resource URLs. So if you have just one servlet, the servlet-name may be an easier way. If you have multiple servlets, url-pattern may be easier.

Comment: If you have simple web application, where all the servlets are handling or generating html and all your URLs for those resources are like *.htm, you can then simply map your session filter using one url-pattern="*.htm"

Answer (score 0):

First off, please don't be misled by the purpose of the tutorial in the link you have specified. Session handling is always done through cookies, URL-rewriting (or for the more advanced, SSL). He's merely using filters to **enhance application security**, by ensuring the user is redirected to the login page, whenever he goes directly to an "avoid-url".

Think about a filter, a physical filter. Whether it be an excel filter or a physical gravel filter. It stands between one thing and another thing:

[image]

Java web filters *can* do the same thing:

[image]

Just like you can choose which water bottle to filter, you can decide which requests you want to filter. You do that using the **filter-mapping** element in **web.xml**. You can specify individual servlet names, or a url pattern.